# How to compress the output when writing to a file?

Tags: haskell, compression, gzip

I have a computation that along with other things generates some data (a lot of it) and I want to write into a file.

The way the code is structured now is (simplified):

```
writeRecord :: Handle -> Record -> IO ()
writeRecord h r = hPutStrLn h (toByteString r)
```

This function is then called periodically during a bigger computation. It is almost like a log, and in fact, multiple files are being written simultaneously.

Now I want the output file to be compressed with `Gzip`.
In languages like Java I would do something like:

```
outStream = new GzipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path))
```

and then would just write into that wrapped output stream.

What is the way of doing it in Haskell?
I think writing something like

```
writeRecord h r = hPut h ((compressed . toByteString) r)
```

is not correct because compressing each small bit individually isn't efficient (I even tried it and the size of the compressed file is bigger than uncompressed this way).

I also don't think that I can just produce a lazy `ByteString` (or even a list of chunks) and then write it with `compressed . fromChunks` because this will require my "generator" building the full thing in memory. And the fact that more than one file is produced at the same time makes it even more complicated.

So what would be a way to solve this in Haskell? Writing to file(s) and have them gzipped?

Comment: The pipes package may be what you need. You can create streams of data from Producers to Consumer, and transform the data in between (with Pipes). I do not know the package enough to write an answer about it, though.

Comment: The Pipes/Conduit _could_ be a solution. It may have extra complexity related to "forking" though: assume that one "generator" wants to write into 5 different files (different data, different rate), therefore there is 1 producer and 5 consumers... Not sure if it will model it nice. 
Also looks a bit overkill for such a simple (as it seems) requirement?

Comment: What opens the handle you are writing to? *That* is where you want to insert the "pipe" through your compressor, just like in your Java example.

Comment: @chepner I do control opening the handle. And that would be ideal if I could "pipe" it through the compressor, but can you point me at _how_ it can be done?

Comment: All of the streaming libraries support familiar forms of compression, see e.g. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/io-streams-1.3.5.0/docs/System-IO-Streams-Zlib.html since it is somewhat java-inspired. But I guess you understand this. It is impossible to give advice because you don't say enough about the way 'many files' is coming into the picture.

Comment: @Michael "many files" is simply a decision that is made by the program. When the computation is running it sometimes can make a decision to write into one of the file handles based on its own internal logic. Say, you anallyze bunch of sources and run a prediction writing your steps and results related to "Trump" and "Clinton" to different files in different formats: `trump.xml`, `trump.json`, `clinton.xml` and `clinton.json`. Something like that. Now you want these files to be compressed.

Comment: @Michael No, not really. It is much simpler: the computation is provided with a number of "sinks" (file handles): and it "knows" when it needs to write to one sink or another while running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing this with conduit is fairly straightforward, though you'd need to adjust your code a bit. I've put together an example of before and after code to demonstrate it. The basic idea is:

- Replace `hPutStr h` with `yield`
- Add some `liftIO` wrappers
- Instead of using `withBinaryFile` or the like, use `runConduitRes`, `gzip`, and `sinkFile`

Here's the example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-6.21 --install-ghc runghc --package conduit-extra
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (MonadIO, liftIO)
import Data.ByteString (ByteString, hPutStr)
import Data.Conduit (ConduitM, (.|), yield, runConduitRes)
import Data.Conduit.Binary (sinkFile)
import Data.Conduit.Zlib (gzip)
import System.IO (Handle)

-- Some helper function you may have
someAction :: IO ByteString
someAction = return "This is a string\n"

-- Original version
producerHandle :: Handle -> IO ()
producerHandle h = do
    str <- someAction
    hPutStr h str

-- Conduit version
producerConduit :: MonadIO m => ConduitM i ByteString m ()
producerConduit = do
    str <- liftIO someAction
    yield str

main :: IO ()
main = runConduitRes $ producerConduit
                    .| gzip
                    .| sinkFile "some-file.txt.gz"
```

You can learn more about conduit in [the conduit tutorial](https://haskell-lang.org/library/conduit).

Your Java idea is interesting, give me a few more minutes, I'll add an answer that looks more like that.

**EDIT**

Here's a version that's closer to your Java style approach. It relies on a `SinkFunc.hs` module which is available as a Gist at: https://gist.github.com/snoyberg/283154123d30ff9e201ea4436a5dd22d

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-6.21 --install-ghc runghc --package conduit-extra
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall -Werror #-}
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import Data.Conduit ((.|))
import Data.Conduit.Binary (sinkHandle)
import Data.Conduit.Zlib (gzip)
import System.IO (withBinaryFile, IOMode (WriteMode))
import SinkFunc (withSinkFunc)

-- Some helper function you may have
someAction :: IO ByteString
someAction = return "This is a string\n"

producerFunc :: (ByteString -> IO ()) -> IO ()
producerFunc write = do
    str <- someAction
    write str

main :: IO ()
main = withBinaryFile "some-file.txt.gz" WriteMode $ \h -> do
    let sink = gzip .| sinkHandle h
    withSinkFunc sink $ \write -> producerFunc write
```

**EDIT 2** One more for good measure, actually using `ZipSink` to stream the data to multiple different files. There are *lots* of different ways of slicing this, but this is one way that works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-6.21 --install-ghc runghc --package conduit-extra
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (MonadResource)
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import Data.Conduit (ConduitM, (.|), yield, runConduitRes, ZipSink (..))
import Data.Conduit.Binary (sinkFile)
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as CL
import Data.Conduit.Zlib (gzip)

data Output = Foo ByteString | Bar ByteString

fromFoo :: Output -> Maybe ByteString
fromFoo (Foo bs) = Just bs
fromFoo _ = Nothing

fromBar :: Output -> Maybe ByteString
fromBar (Bar bs) = Just bs
fromBar _ = Nothing

producer :: Monad m => ConduitM i Output m ()
producer = do
    yield $ Foo "This is going to Foo"
    yield $ Bar "This is going to Bar"

sinkHelper :: MonadResource m
           => FilePath
           -> (Output -> Maybe ByteString)
           -> ConduitM Output o m ()
sinkHelper fp f
    = CL.mapMaybe f
   .| gzip
   .| sinkFile fp

main :: IO ()
main = runConduitRes
     $ producer
    .| getZipSink
            (ZipSink (sinkHelper "foo.txt.gz" fromFoo) *>
             ZipSink (sinkHelper "bar.txt.gz" fromBar))
```

Comment: I didn't see the comments before, I was just answering the original question. If that's really what the questioner is looking for, it would involve something like `ZipSink` in conduit, _or_ this other approach that I'm writing up right now as a proof of concept.

Comment: Also, generally speaking, even if something is "simple," a working example is usually much easier to grok for someone new to the library.

Answer (score 5):

All the streaming libraries support compression. If I understand the particular problem and the way you are thinking about it, `io-streams` might be the simplest for your purposes. Here I alternate between writing to `trump` and `clinton` output streams, which are written as compressed files. I follow by showing the `pipes` equivalent of Michael's `conduit` program

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-6.21 --install-ghc runghc --package io-streams
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified System.IO.Streams as IOS
import qualified System.IO as IO
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)

analyzer :: IOS.OutputStream ByteString -> IOS.OutputStream ByteString -> IO ()
analyzer clinton trump = do 
  IOS.write (Just "This is a string\n") clinton
  IOS.write (Just "This is a string\n") trump
  IOS.write (Just "Clinton string\n") clinton
  IOS.write (Just "Trump string\n") trump   
  IOS.write (Just "Another Clinton string\n") clinton
  IOS.write (Just "Another Trump string\n") trump   
  IOS.write Nothing clinton
  IOS.write Nothing trump

main:: IO ()
main = 
  IOS.withFileAsOutput "some-file-clinton.txt.gz" $ \clinton_compressed ->
  IOS.withFileAsOutput "some-file-trump.txt.gz" $ \trump_compressed -> do
     clinton <- IOS.gzip IOS.defaultCompressionLevel clinton_compressed
     trump <- IOS.gzip IOS.defaultCompressionLevel trump_compressed
     analyzer clinton trump
```

Obviously you can mix all kinds of `IO` in `analyzer` between acts of writing to the two output streams - I'm just show in the `write`s, so to speak. In particular, if `analyzer` is understood as depending on an input stream, the `write`s can depend on `read`s from the input stream. [Here's](http://sprunge.us/ajHR) a (slightly!) more complicated program that does that.  If I run the program above I see

```
$ stack gzip_so.hs  
$ gunzip some-file-clinton.txt.gz 
$ gunzip some-file-trump.txt.gz 
$ cat some-file-clinton.txt 
This is a string
Clinton string
Another Clinton string
$ cat some-file-trump.txt 
This is a string
Trump string
Another Trump string
```

With pipes and conduit there are various ways of achieving the above effect, with a higher level of decomposition of parts. Writing to separate files will however be a little more subtle. Here in any case is the pipes equivalent of Michael S's conduit program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-6.21 --install-ghc runghc  --package pipes-zlib 
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (MonadIO, liftIO)
import Data.ByteString (ByteString, hPutStr)
import System.IO  (IOMode(..), withFile, Handle)
import Pipes  
import qualified Pipes.ByteString as PB
import qualified Pipes.GZip as P

-- Some helper function you may have
someAction :: IO ByteString
someAction = return "This is a string\n"

-- Original version
producerHandle :: Handle -> IO ()
producerHandle h = do
    str <- someAction
    hPutStr h str

producerPipe :: MonadIO m => Producer ByteString m ()
producerPipe = do
    str <- liftIO someAction
    yield str

main :: IO ()
main =  withFile "some-file-pipes.txt.gz"  WriteMode $ \h -> 
     runEffect $ P.compress P.defaultCompression producerPipe  >-> PB.toHandle h
```

-- Edit

Here for what it's worth is yet another way of superimposing several producers on a single thread with pipes or conduit, to add to the different approaches Michael S and `danidiaz` mentioned:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-6.21 --install-ghc runghc --package pipes-zlib
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Pipes
import Pipes.GZip
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
import qualified Pipes.ByteString as Bytes
import System.IO
import Control.Monad (replicateM_)

producer = replicateM_ 50000 $ do
    marie  "This is going to Marie\n"  -- arbitary IO can be interspersed here
    arthur "This is going to Arthur\n" -- with liftIO
    sylvia "This is going to Sylvia\n" 
  where 
    marie = yield; arthur = lift . yield; sylvia = lift . lift . yield

sinkHelper h p = runEffect (compress bestSpeed p >-> Bytes.toHandle h)

main :: IO ()
main =  
   withFile "marie.txt.gz" WriteMode $ \marie ->
   withFile "arthur.txt.gz"  WriteMode $ \arthur -> 
   withFile "sylvia.txt.gz"  WriteMode $ \sylvia ->
      sinkHelper sylvia
      $ sinkHelper arthur
      $ sinkHelper marie
      $ producer
```

It is quite simple and fast, and can be written in conduit with the obvious alterations - but finding it natural involves a higher level of buy-in with the 'monad transformer stack' point of view. It would be the most natural way of writing such a program from the point of view of something like the [`streaming`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming) library.

Answer (score 3):

For incremental compression, I think you could make use of `compressIO`/`foldCompressStream` in `Codec.Compression.Zlib.Internal`.

If you're able to represent your producer action as an `IO (Maybe a)` (such as an `MVar` take or `InputStream`/`Chan` read) where  `Nothing` signifies end of input, something like this should work:

```
import System.IO (Handle)
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Codec.Compression.Zlib.Internal as ZLib

compressedWriter :: Handle -> (IO (Maybe BS.ByteString)) -> IO ()
compressedWriter handle source =
  ZLib.foldCompressStream
    (\next -> source >>= maybe (next BS.empty) next)
    (\chunk next -> BS.hPut handle chunk >> next)
    (return ())
    (ZLib.compressIO ZLib.rawFormat ZLib.defaultCompressParams)
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is similar to Michael Snoyman's **EDIT 2**, but uses the [*foldl*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl), *pipes*, [*pipes-zlib*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-zlib) and [*streaming-eversion*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-eversion) packages.

```
 {-# language OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

-- cabal install bytestring foldl pipes pipes-zlib streaming-eversion
import Data.Foldable
import Data.ByteString
import qualified Control.Foldl as L 
import Pipes 
import qualified Pipes.Prelude
import Pipes.Zlib (compress,defaultCompression,defaultWindowBits)
import Streaming.Eversion.Pipes (transvertMIO)
import System.IO

type Tag = String

producer :: Monad m => Producer (Tag,ByteString) m ()
producer = do
    yield $ ("foo","This is going to Foo")
    yield $ ("bar","This is going to Bar")

foldForTag :: Handle -> Tag -> L.FoldM IO (Tag,ByteString) ()
foldForTag handle tag = 
      L.premapM (\(tag',bytes) -> if tag' == tag then Just bytes else Nothing)
    . L.handlesM L.folded
    . transvertMIO (compress defaultCompression defaultWindowBits)
    $ L.mapM_ (Data.ByteString.hPut handle)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    withFile "foo.txt" WriteMode $ \h1 ->
        withFile "bar.txt" WriteMode $ \h2 ->
            let multifold = traverse_ (uncurry foldForTag) [(h1,"foo"),(h2,"bar")] 
            in  L.impurely Pipes.Prelude.foldM multifold producer
```

Comment: I added a `Streaming.Zip` with a `gzip`  https://github.com/michaelt/streaming-utils/blob/master/Streaming/Zip.hs#L185

Comment: @Michael That's great, thanks. I wasn't aware of the existence of "streaming-utils".

Answer (score 1):

This solution is similar to Michael Snoyman's **EDIT 2**, but uses the [streaming](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming), [streaming-bytestring](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-bytestring), pipes and [pipes-zlib](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-zlib) packages.

```
{-# language OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

-- cabal install bytestring streaming streaming-bytestring pipes pipes-zlib 
import Data.ByteString
import qualified Data.ByteString.Streaming as B
import Streaming
import qualified Streaming.Prelude as S
import Pipes (next)
import qualified Pipes.Prelude 
import Pipes.Zlib (compress,defaultCompression,defaultWindowBits)
import System.IO

type Tag = String

producer :: Monad m => Stream (Of (Tag,ByteString)) m ()
producer = do
    S.yield ("foo","This is going to Foo")
    S.yield ("bar","This is going to Bar")

-- I couldn't find a streaming-zlib on Hackage, took a pipes detour
compress' :: MonadIO m 
          => Stream (Of ByteString) m r -> Stream (Of ByteString) m r 
compress' = S.unfoldr Pipes.next
          . compress defaultCompression defaultWindowBits
          . Pipes.Prelude.unfoldr S.next     

keepTag :: Monad m 
        => Tag -> Stream (Of (Tag,ByteString)) m r -> Stream (Of ByteString) m r 
keepTag tag = S.map snd . S.filter ((tag==) . fst)

main :: IO ()
main = runResourceT 
     . B.writeFile "foo.txt" . B.fromChunks . compress' .  keepTag "foo"  
     . B.writeFile "bar.txt"  . B.fromChunks . compress' . keepTag "bar"  
     $ S.copy producer
```

I make use of the [copy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.1.4.3/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:copy) function from [Streaming.Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.1.4.3/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html), that allows you to

> Duplicate the content of stream, so that it can be acted on twice in
>   different ways, but without breaking streaming.